# Проблема при перенаправлении через RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте! В действии контролера выполняется перенаправление к другому действию этого же контролера. Результат: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". GetData вызывается через ajax-запрос в JQuery.При перенаправлении получается запрос url http://localhost:61327/Home/Index/qwertyQWERTY%20HTTP/1.1. Запрос адреса http://localhost:61327/Home/Index/qwertyQWERTY срабатывает нормально. Код контролера, ajax-запроса и RouteConfig.cs приведён ниже. Просьба помочь.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Cars_project_3
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{d}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", d = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default1",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{data}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetData", data = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Cars_project_3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index(string d)
        {
            Repository repository = new Repository();
            ViewBag.ViewbagValues = repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders();
            Response.Write("Ku-ku");
            Response.Write(d);            
            return View(repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]        
        public ActionResult GetData(string data)
        {            
            Response.Write(Request.InputStream);
            Response.Write("qwerty");            
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {d="qwertyQWERTY"});            
        }

    }
}


function SendDataToController(data) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "text",
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Data was send to the controller");
            window.location = result.URL;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: data was not send to the controller");
        }
    });
    alert(data);
```

}

Comment: зачем у вас два равнозначных роута? начнити с удаления второго, и дальше у вас все будет хорошо

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: от 404 избавило?

Comment: Нет. Суть проблемы, как я понимаю, в том, что в url добавляется %20HTTP/1.1.

Comment: суть проблемы в том, что вы пишите в респонс и тут же делаете редирект, при этом у вас два роутинга выполняющих один функционал, избавтесь от второго, и в методе GetData входящий параметр будет так же d. Уберите запись в респонс из метода GetData

Comment: Теперь перенаправление идёт по адресу http://localhost:61327/undefined%20HTTP/1.1. Результат такой же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. В такой ситуации нельзя использовать одновременно перенаправление и ajax. Ссылка на объяснение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453749/redirecting-via-redirecttoaction-gives-404-status?noredirect=1#comment54706804_33453749

Answer (score 0):

роутинг

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

контроллер

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        var repository = new Repository();
        ViewBag.ViewbagValues = repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders();          
        return View(repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]        
    public ActionResult GetData(string id)
    {                     
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new {id="qwertyQWERTY"});            
    }
}
```

**UPD:**
Ajax запрос

```
function SendDataToController(data) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:data},
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Data was send to the controller");
            $(location).attr('href', result.URL);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: data was not send to the controller");
        }
    });
    alert(data);  
}
```

Остались вопросы, как вы собираетесь делать редирект после выполнения аякс запроса, если его делает сервер?

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: @AN90 и как же вы в этот метод обращаетесь? Ладно, пойдем другим путем, раз у вас 404, значит вы незнаете разницу в `POST` и `GET`. это все меняет, удалите `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Если речь о GetData, то к нему я обращаюсь через ajax-запрос в JQuery. Опять не работает.

Comment: @AN90 ajax запрос покажите

Comment: Добавил в вопросе.

Comment: @AN90, обновил ответ

Comment: Перенаправление HTTP/1.1 200 OK, но действие Index не срабатывает, страница не обновляется.

Comment: @AN90, вы в этом уверены? перед тем как отправить аякс запрос, поставте точку остановки на Index

Comment: Я смотрю в Fiddler.

Comment: @AN90 смотрите в отладчике локально

Comment: Я добавил в действии Index запись данных в ответ. Их нет. Страница не обновляется. Что именно и где смотреть?

Comment: поставте точку остановки на методе Index и смотрите когда туда будет переход, если вам нравится респонс, добавте вывод респонсом, но из Index а не из GetData. И вообще, я не могу вас понять, что вы хотите получить на выходе? В данный момент редирект отрабатывает на ура, но что вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы данные из одного действия попали в другое, а затем были выведены на странице.

Comment: @AN90 а одним действием обработать данные и вывести на страницу никак? если уж хотите использовать второе действие, то делать это лучше по другому, посмотрите в сторону загрузки аяксом паршел вью

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает, если адрес не содержит %20HTTP/1.1 (захожу по адресу просто в браузере). Я хочу, чтобы страница обновлялась, поэтому перенаправляю на Index, который формирует представление.

Comment: @AN90 Ну так кто мешает с Index на Index перенаправить?

Comment: Всё-таки хотелось бы разобраться с этим вопросом.

Comment: @AN90 В моем ответе есть все, что вам нужно, дальше уже обвешивайте данными как душе угодно

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо за помощь!