# Получения url страницы в ajax запросе

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть ajax запрос. Результатом которого если всё хорошо будет срабатывать

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

И как оказывается что бы перенаправить на другую страницу, в результате выполнения ajax запроса нужно ещё и сменить location самому, или останешься на той же странице. Нашёл варианты как это можно сделать [Проблема при перенаправлении через RedirectToAction](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462391/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-redirecttoaction)
Но почему то когда я пытаюсь использовать результат выполнения ajax запроса там нет url как в примере. В результате мне возвращается html view Index. Подскажите пожалуйста может я делаю что то не так?
Вот мой код
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(Client client)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Ajax запрос у меня сделан с помощью хелпера `Ajax.Beginform` поэтому не вижу смысла приводить весь код страницы, показываю функцию Success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Success(result) {
        $(location).attr('href', result.url);
    }
</script>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если Вы делаете AJAX запрос, то URL нужно возвращать клиенту и на клиенте перенаправлять: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458556/3129992

Comment: @XelaNimed спасибо. Просто в той теме которую я скинул этого не было, вот и не понял в чём дело. Значит там немного не правильно написано.

Comment: В той теме правильно написано,  `В такой ситуации нельзя использовать одновременно перенаправление и ajax`

Comment: @tym32167 понял.

Comment: @tym32167 а может подскажите, у меня просто в связи с этой темой появился ещё вопрос, или если нужно задам новый. Вот выполнился у меня ajax запрос. И я хочу вызвать alert, но вызвать я хочу его уже на другой странице, на той на которую перенаправляю. При моих попытка вызвать этот alert сразу же после `$(location).attr('href', result.url);` или например в ajaxstop но всё равно быстро моргает окно алерта и после сразу же идёт перенаправление. А как сделать так что бы перенаправилась страница, а потом только вызвался алерт и не пропадал, как и должно быть если б я вызвал его без перенаправления.

Comment: Это несвязанный вопрос, задавайте новой темой.

Comment: Отдельные вопросы задавайте отдельными вопросами

Comment: @tym32167, сделал отдельный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928344/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: @AK задал новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928344/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы выполняете AJAX запрос к серверу, то все заголовки HTTP перенаправлений будут возвращаться обратно клиенту, но не напрямую браузеру, а в Вашу функцию обратного вызова AJAX (success, done, then...).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Registration",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { you: 'data', is: 'here'},
    success: function(result){
        window.location.href = result.url;
    }
});
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(Client client) {

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var data = new { url = Url.Action("Index", "YouControllerName")};
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return View();
}
```

---

Ссылки по теме

- [RedirectToAction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
- [HTTP перенаправления](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)
- [Различие в использования location replace, href и assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703689/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-replace-and-window-loca)