# Вызов алерта после редиректа

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть форма на которой выполняется ajax запрос, в итоге выполнения происходит перенаправление на другую страницу. `$(location).attr('href', result.url);` При моих попытка вызвать этот alert сразу же после `$(location).attr('href', result.url);` или например в ajaxstop но всё равно быстро моргает окно алерта и после сразу же идёт перенаправление. А как сделать так что бы перенаправилась страница, а потом только вызвался алерт и не пропадал, как и должно быть если б я вызвал его без перенаправления.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос с EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18048338/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 0):

При перенаправлении загружаемая страница не знает ничего о том, что ей необходимо что-то отображать. Для решения Вашей задачи необходимо передать параметры целевой странице:

```
// перенаправление
window.location.href = redirectUrl + '?alert=1&alertMessage=This+is+simple+message'

// на целевой странице
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/3129992
function getUrlParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
        url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!results[2]) {
        return '';
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if(getUrlParameterByName('alert')){
        var msg = getUrlParameterByName('alertMessage');
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```